# "A micro-manual for Scheme"?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Given that LISP apparently can be expressed in "10 rules" of "A micro-manual for LISP" [[1]](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0ZnV_0C-Q7IOTRkNzVjZjMtMWE1NC00YzQ3LTgzMWEtM2UwY2I1YzdmNmM5/edit?hl=en)[[2]](http://www.scribd.com/doc/35653787/Untitled?secret_password=12o8ou3kcax00s47xv3y#full) (is this true?), is there a similarly succinct description of Scheme?

Comment: Yes, same applies to Scheme. Remember, Scheme and Common lisp have different philosophies but both are based on concepts introduced by LISP.

Comment: But for example, AFAIK, Common (?) Lisp has dynamic scoping, and Scheme has lexical scoping (?) - so is this distinction not clear from the "10 rules" yet? (I just skimmed over them, because I'm not sure if I'll need them in the end)

Comment: @akavel: Common Lisp defaults to lexical scoping, but can introduce dynamic scoping by suitable declarations (done automatically for symbols bound using DEFVAR or DEFPARAMETER).

Answer (score 1):

McCarthy's "10 Rules" here are essentially an early form of operational semantics. This document comes from 1978, and is written 3 years after the first Scheme Report, wherein Abelson & Steele pull out the simple bits of LISP to create Scheme.  Both Scheme and LISP are moving targets, so you have to qualify comparisons by saying, e.g., "this matches the scheme *of its day*." I claim that you can regard this micro-manual as applying equally to Scheme and LISP.

FWIW, McCarthy's rule for function evaluation (below) uses the phrase "in the original environment", which appears to require capture-avoiding substitution, and thus lexical scoping.

> "9. *value ((LAMBDA (v<sub>1</sub> ... v<sub>n</sub>) e) e<sub>1</sub> ... e<sub>n</sub>)* is the same as *value e* but in an environment in which the variables *v<sub>1</sub> ... v<sub>n</sub>* take the
>   values of the expressions *e<sub>1</sub> ... e<sub>1</sub>* **in the original environment**." [emphasis mine]

Comment: hmh; I'm trying to analyze this sentence, but can't get it for now :/ which is the original environment? did *e_1...e_n* have any values in "original environment" at all?

Comment: The original environment is the one in which the function call occurs. The values referred to are the result of evaluating e_1 ... e_n in those environments. A simple case is something like (f (+ n 1)), where it's important that n get the value of n in the current environment, rather than one defined in the body of f. The more interesting case occurs with something like (f (lambda () n)), where we again want n to get the value of n in the current environment, even though the variable reference can't be reduced to a value yet. Wish I had more space / better formatting....

Comment: Follow-on comment: McCarthy's text is not really very airtight here; to find a more precise specification, look to things like the lambda calculus or the later Scheme reports.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that, at 43 pages, the best succinct description of Scheme is [the original.](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-349.pdf) But, then again, I'm a Common Lisp programmer.